# Raise an SSIS event in Script Task when debug mode is manually exited

Tags: c#, .net, events, ssis

Is there a way to catch when the user stops an SSIS package from running while in debug mode inside of a Script Task (C#)?

I have a package that executes a .exe file within a Script Task. If for some reason the user starts and stops the package while in debug mode, the .exe hangs in the background and can only be stopped by ending the process in Windows' Task Manager. My goal is to stop the .exe from running following the user stopping the SSIS package manually while in debug mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is not possible within SSIS...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/db384aee-0041-46a2-b855-b60a74f6e0bd/ssis-even-handler-whenever-the-process-stop-by-sql-server-job?forum=sqlintegrationservices